# Getting a decimal qty from subtracting two times

Tags: php

How do I subtract two time variables from each other with the answer as a decimal number? My time variables look like this: `07:32:00`

I am looking for something like this:

```
$total = $start_time - $end_time
echo "$time Hours";
```

Output to look like this:

```
5.3 Hours
```

Comment: Find the difference in minutes, divide by 60. `318 / 60 = 5.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant subtract on strings. Your variable "07:32:00" is a string.

You will have to convert the time to Unix timestamp with the php function  [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

And you aslo have to subtract from the largest time.

Here is the solution:

```
echo (strtotime("15:00:00") - strtotime("11:30:00"))/(60*60);
```

Comment: Thank you @Anders Andersen, It was the strtotime that I missed.